# Is Jake Wheat's "Intro to Parsing with Parsec in Haskell" outdated?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am following [an incredibly detailed Parsec tutorial](http://jakewheat.github.io/intro_to_parsing/). However, some examples do not work as expected, e.g.,

```hs
ghci> parseWithWhitespace simpleExpr5 "(1+2)"
Left (line 1, column 3):
unexpected "+"
expecting digit or ")"
```

Is it because the tutorial is [outdated](https://github.com/JakeWheat/intro_to_parsing/issues/11)? Has anyone tried it recently?

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in the tutorial. `term5` should be

```
term5 = term simpleExpr5
```